# Oracle 10g: How insert conditionally rows from table A to B based

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

Got a table A like this

```
|----------|----------|
|  DT      |  FLAG    |
|----------|----------|
| 2015-MAY |  E       |
| 2015-JUN |  H       |
| 2015-OCT |  S       |
| 2016-FEB |  E       |
|----------|----------|
```

I want to insert in B the rows for which the `flag` aggregated data of A match a given pattern.

This query do the aggregation below:

```
     SELECT
            (lag(rep.flag) over (ORDER BY rep.DECLARATIONPERIOD) || flag) AS ERRCODE,
            (lag(rep.DECLARATIONPERIOD) over (ORDER BY rep.DECLARATIONPERIOD)) AS DECFROM, DECLARATIONPERIOD AS DECTO
    FROM  XE_ERR_OVLP rep;
```

Result (table A):

```
|----------|---------------|---------------|
|  FLAG    |  DTFROM       |  DTFTO        |
|----------|---------------|---------------|
|  VV      |    2014-02-01 |    2014-03-01 |
|  VE      |    2014-03-01 |    2014-04-01 |
|  EE      |    2014-04-01 |    2014-05-01 |
|  EV      |    2014-05-01 |    2014-06-01 |
|  VV      |    2014-06-01 |    2014-07-01 |
|  VS      |    2014-07-01 |    2014-08-31 |
|----------|---------------|---------------|
```

See [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7f62a9/1)

I would like to populate this table (B) from the table (A), for the value of FLAG that match certain value only (eg `EE` and `HH`):

```
|----------|---------------|---------------|
|  FLAG    |  DTFROM       |  DTFTO        |
|----------|---------------|---------------|
|  ...     | ...           | ...           |
|----------|---------------| --------------|
```

If possible on the fly (while aggregating).

Any suggestion to get it right welcome

Comment: I'm missing something...  Are you familiar with the [`SELECT INTO`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/selectinto_statement.htm) syntax?  Why isn't this just a `select * into B From A where A.Flag in ('EE','HH')`?

Comment: Yes. The problem is how can I make a conditional select based on the value of `(lag(flag) over (ORDER BY DECLARATIONPERIOD) || flag)` ? I have edit my question showing the problem I have using insert into

Comment: It's not clear why you're using `LAG()`. The logic described in your question is covered by xQbert's comment. What additional logic are you trying to implement and why is it not working? What is your expected result and why?

Comment: Sample data  & expected results would help clarify the question.  I see that two values of flag seem to be combined into HS or SE or EE or whatever.... but the question doesn't align to the data.   usually when using analytics which you want to evaluate you need to use a CTE or a derived table to materialize the result before  you can filter on it.  So maybe wrap the inner select in a select then apply the where clause.

Comment: Sorry, clarified the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an order of operation issue: Note we materialize the results of the analytic using a derived table before we filter on it.  The SELECT doesn't execute until the where clause has been executed so the ERRCODE alias is unknown to the where clause.

SQL order of operations can be found online, I'm not going to [restate](https://blog.jooq.org/2016/12/09/a-beginners-guide-to-the-true-order-of-sql-operations/); but in this case the below are the important elements/order. You'll note the link specifically states your issue: Window functions ... are not available to the WHERE clause, which happened before the evaluation of the window function.

1. FROM
2. WHERE
3. SELECT

This means the WHERE Clause doesn't know about ERRCODE yet; so it can't limit by it.  This is generally solved by using a derived table/inline view or a common table expression.

Here's the inline view/derived table:

```
   INSERT INTO XE_ERR_RANG
      SELECT Z.* 
      FROM (SELECT EMPLOYERID
                 , EMPLOYEEID
                 , lag(DECLARATIONPERIOD) over (ORDER BY DECLARATIONPERIOD) AS DECFROM
                 , DECLARATIONPERIOD AS DECTO
                 , lag(flag) over (ORDER BY DECLARATIONPERIOD) || flag AS ERRCODE
            FROM XE_ERR_OVLP) Z
      WHERE Z.ERRCODE in ('HS', 'SE');
```

Alternative approach using a common table expression (CTE):

Untested: but you said oracle 10g appears to support CTE; but not recursion; so should work if it supports the insert syntax before the CTE...

```
INSERT INTO XE_ERR_RANG

WITH Z as (SELECT EMPLOYERID
                , EMPLOYEEID
                , lag(DECLARATIONPERIOD) over (ORDER BY DECLARATIONPERIOD) AS DECFROM
                , DECLARATIONPERIOD AS DECTO
                , lag(flag) over (ORDER BY DECLARATIONPERIOD) || flag AS ERRCODE
           FROM XE_ERR_OVLP)

SELECT * 
FROM Z
WHERE ERRCODE in ('HS', 'SE');
```

Comment: That's exactly that !! Thank you very much. Marked correct and up voted.

Comment: So CTE approach should be faster ? Note: trying it, it says: Error(183,12): PL/SQL: ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword

Comment: Sorry insert has to go before the CTE start (updated above). I wouldn't say it's any faster; just cleaner to read/maintain. Inline views/derived tables go by the wayside when a CTE is available for readability/maintainability. (IMO)   Also added some text to support why and more on Order of operations for SQL.  Very important to understand in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

This does what you describe:

```
insert into b (dt, flag)
    select dt, flag
    from a
    where flag in ('E', 'H');
```

I'm not sure how it relates to the queries, which are considerably more complicated than your sample data and question.

Comment: I want to insert aggregated data from A on the fly into B, for some aggregated values only